# laravel use artisan to make database migration

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel, hopefully someone could help me please.

The project now has migrations and seeds, which I need to put it in mySQL. I followed the instructions from the official sites in both installing laravel and making migrations processes. The .env file is also set correctly. However, I have no idea why I cannot use artisan. Whenever I tried it, it says

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                 
  Missing client credentials key [identifier] from options.
```

I have tried to use composer to update (mentioned here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/problems-installing-my-site-on-forge ), but it did not work.

This is the output when I run update or install

```
yang$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize


  [InvalidArgumentException]                                 
  Missing client credentials key [identifier] from options.  


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

.env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:8X53w+XiVDnB+2gA8jdgDwGQy2bpDhkUGlaICXZTpC4=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=oplserver
DB_USERNAME=opl
DB_PASSWORD=Guo123

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

database.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'toor'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

autoload.php

```
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Composer Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Include The Compiled Class File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| To dramatically increase your application's performance, you may use a
| compiled class file which contains all of the classes commonly used
| by a request. The Artisan "optimize" is used to create this file.
|
*/

$compiledPath = __DIR__.'/cache/compiled.php';

if (file_exists($compiledPath)) {
    require $compiledPath;
}
```

Please give me some suggestion, thank you!

Comment: If you delet your `.env` file make sure your config file has your KEY

Comment: try `composer  self-update` it will update latest your composer latest version globally or in your project path

Comment: are you using forge for your hosting?

Comment: Hi Raj, thanks for apply. I tried composer self-update, it says "You are already using composer version 1.1.3 (stable channel).". There is an App_key in my .env file, but to be honest I am not sure where it comes from. BTW, I also tried to use "php artisan key:generate" to get one, but it does not work, the same error came out.

Comment: Hi, Achraf. I am really new to lavarel, just joined a new team because of manpower shortage, so I am not sure what you mean about forge hosting. But if it is about server. I put the whole lavarel project under apache, and edited the document path to the lavarel project (to be honest, I even do not know whether this way is right, but at least it is able to run and access the website and do my work).

Comment: alright, share your .env file and config/database.php

Comment: I have updated the post. Please check it

Comment: this is realy wierd, did you change anything beside the migrations and seeds? did you change your bootstrap/autoload.php

Comment: No... I have also put my autoload.php on post, you can check it. The only thing I changed is the write access permission of some files when I tried to run the project up. I tried to use artisan in a brand new project, which is working. May you please use the Answer area, because it says avoid extended discussion in comments.

Comment: and the .env file in this project is copied from the brand new project, will this  be a problem? What is the best way to generate the .env from scratch (.env.example) as I do not know how to generate the App_key